# Insert excel file in SQLite Database in Iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite, iphone-sdk-3.2

We have a requirement to insert a excel/pdf file into SQLite database filed.How can we do this ? Is it possible to convert the excel/pdf file in some binary format and then insert into a blob field in DB? We don't want to save the files in the documents directory and store the file names in sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

why not save the files in the documents directory and store the file names in sqlite?